# Android String reference to shared preferences cannot be iterated?

Tags: java, android, reference, sharedpreferences

So I have an ArrayList named locationsList. I also have SharedPreferences that hold a city name which was set in the previous activity which i want to add onto my ArrayList. BUT I want to add it with a ">" at the end of it. So for example

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
locationsList.add(0, prefs.getString("city", "no city") + ">");
```

However it does not change!!!. the ">" Isn't added. I even tried adding it when i set the text of the textView.

```
TextView tv...;
tv.setText(locationsList.get(0) + ">");
```

I dont understand why it cant change. Obviously the array list is holding a reference to the preferences and that cannot change. But I even tried assigning the preferences to a string variable and then iterating it, it doesn't budge. Can anyone help me

Async in activity

```
class getLocationsUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", prefs.getString("city", "durban")));

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(IMAGE_URL + "fetchlocations.php", "POST",   
params);

        try {

            list = json.getJSONArray("posts");

            for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);
                String location = c.getString("location");

                tempList.add(location);
                Log.d("async trend", trendList.get(0));
            }

            Log.d("Got list", imageUrl.get(0) + " " + trendList.get(0));

        } catch(JSONException je) {
            Log.d("json exception", "json exception");
            je.printStackTrace();   
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        locationsList = tempList;
        locationsFragment.updateAdapter();
        feedFragment.updateHeadingAdapter();
    }
}
```

FeedFragment set up in onCreateView

```
    headingPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.headingPager);

    headingList = (ArrayList<String>) NightWatch.locationsList.clone();
    added = prefs.getString("city", "makaka");
    headingList.add(0, added + ">");

    headingAdapter = new CustomHeadingPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    headingPager.setAdapter(headingAdapter);
```

FeedFragments CustomHeadingAdapter

```
    public class CustomHeadingPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public CustomHeadingPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        return HeadingFragment.newInstance(arg0, headingList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return headingList.size();
    }

}
```

FeedFragment's updateHeadingAdapter() called from the Async

```
    public void updateHeadingAdapter() {
    headingList = (ArrayList<String>) NightWatch.locationsList.clone();
    headingList.add(0, (prefs.getString("city", "null") + ">"));
    headingAdapter = new CustomHeadingPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    headingPager.setAdapter(headingAdapter);
}
```

And finally the HeadingFragment that I return in the adapter.

```
   package info.nightowl.nightowl;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.nightowl.R;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HeadingFragment extends Fragment{

int position;
Typeface font;
ArrayList<String> list;
SharedPreferences prefs;

static HeadingFragment newInstance(int position, ArrayList<String> list) {

    final HeadingFragment f = new HeadingFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    args.putStringArrayList("list", list);

    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    list = getArguments().getStringArrayList("list");
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
            "NotCourierSans.ttf");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.heading_viewpage_layout, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.headingText);

    if(position == 0) tv.setText(">" + list.get(position) + ">");
    else tv.setText(list.get(position) + ">");

    tv.setTypeface(font);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    tv.setTextSize(30);


    return v;

}
}
```

Comment: can you post more code/

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @RolfSmit but there must be. Why isnt it changing!!!. When I say tv.setText("<"+ locationsList.get(0)) Then it does change only when the ">" is in the beginning????

Comment: I'm suspecting your new code is some how not compiling to a new APK file and your running the old file? Could this be the case? Running this code in my environment works fine.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code sample?

Comment: @RolfSmit Are you using context.getSharedPreferences or PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences???

Comment: That doesn't matter, they just return a different shared preferences file.

Comment: I suggest you add some more code.

Comment: @RolfSmit Okay I edited in the code

Comment: What if you output it to the log before adding it to the list? Like this: Log.d("Test", city + ">"); What do you see?

Comment: It works in my setup with this code: String test = "city"; Log.d("Test", test + ">");

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Always remember when iterating to a string text vi you set it to be a single line in the xml so...

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Kind of a dumb mistake really

Comment: First, the word is "appending" not "iterating".  And this change is not very credible as a solution - rather it looks like a random coincidence with whatever finally got you testing your actual source code.